# How can I get my python script to ignore specific characters in my csv file?

Tags: python, pandas, regex

I have data in a csv file that contains car loan data.

The columns are the car make and model, the total cost, and the APR.

So I am using pyPlot and Python to make Pie charts for each make...the pie chart will contain the models for each car manufacturer where the size of the pie section will be determined by how high the APR is and how much the total cost is.

I am trying to use this library: `matplotlib.pyplot`

But it doesn't like the dollar signs or percentages.  Is there a way to fix this?

```
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
Toyota, Rav4,"$25,814.73",$315.00,3.24%
                          ^
```

Here is the script:

```
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

# Read data 
file_path = 'input_data.csv'
data = pd.read_csv(file_path, encoding='unicode_escape')

columns = data.columns


for column in columns:

    if pd.api.types.is_numeric_dtype(data[column]):
        # Ignore symbols
        data[column] = pd.to_numeric(data[column].replace('[\%,]', '', regex=True), errors='coerce')

        # Plot 
        colors = plt.cm.Set3.colors  
        plt.pie(data[column], labels=data.index, autopct='%1.1f%%', colors=colors, startangle=140)
        plt.title(f'Pie Chart for {column}')
        plt.show()
    else:
        print(f"Skipping non-numeric column: {column}")
```

full error:

```
SyntaxWarning: invalid escape sequence '\%'
data[column] = pd.to_numeric(data[column].replace('[\%,]', '', 
regex=True), errors='coerce')
```

Comment: Do you really get a `SyntaxError`? What's the complete traceback?

Comment: Here is the error when I run it in de bug mode:  `SyntaxWarning: invalid escape sequence '\%'
  data[column] = pd.to_numeric(data[column].replace('[\%,]', '', regex=True), errors='coerce')`

Comment: Get rid of the backslash before `%` in `.replace()`

Comment: That's valid CSV. Something's not right with how it's being parsed. Might be time to file a bug report in the pandas library.

Comment: (Please don’t respond in comments. If your question is unclear, you want to [edit] it to fix it, and probably then remove your now-redundant comment.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should remove `%` and `$` from your data.

For instance, let's suppose we have the following dataframe:

```
      Car Model       Price   Rebate %Rebate
0  Toyota  Rav4  $25,814.73  $315.00   3.24%
```

**A possible solution:**

A possible solution is to delete first the symbols `%` and `$`

```py
import pandas as pd

data = {
    'Car': ["Toyota"],
    'Model': ["Rav4"],
    'Price': ["$25,814.73"],
    'Rebate': ["$315.00"],
    '%Rebate': ["3.24%"]
}

df = pd.DataFrame(data)

# Remove dollar signs
df['Price'] = pd.to_numeric(df['Price'].replace('[$,]', '', regex=True), errors='coerce')
df['Rebate'] = pd.to_numeric(df['Price'].replace('[$,]', '', regex=True), errors='coerce')
# Remove percentages
df['%Rebate'] = pd.to_numeric(df['%Rebate'].replace('[%,]', '', regex=True), errors='coerce')

print(df)
```

Result:

```
      Car Model     Price    Rebate  %Rebate
0  Toyota  Rav4  25814.73  25814.73     3.24
```

**Suggestion:**

You could write a function to simplify the task, like this:

```py
def remove_symb(column, symbol):
    return pd.to_numeric(column.replace(f'[{symbol},]', '', regex=True), errors='coerce')

df['Price'] = remove_symb(df['Price'], symbol='$')
```